# Web Application on top of Spring Boot Restful Services + Cross Application Session Sharing

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm thinking about 2 projects running on 2 different ports/servers.

1. A Spring Boot "Backend Application" (secured by SSO/OAuth2) that hosts Restful Services
2. A Jsp/Spring MVC/plain HTML5 "Web Application" that runs on a web server like tomcat and internally invokes the backend services in project1

For (1) Spring Boot App, I'm able to enable SSO through simple configuration. For (2), Spring Security App, I had to write 8-10 classes to handle SSO/OAuth2 and related stuff. I'm just wanted to know if there is any simple way of redirecting Project2 to Project1 for Authentication so that I can avoid maintenance of those additional OAuth2 classes I developed for Spring Security.

I know that we may face issues like CSRF but am just curious to know more about this.

Comment: Have a look at Spring Cloud – especially Zuul.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the info